# difference if I put the DateAdd function between the SELECT and FROM and FROM and WHERE

Tags: c#, winforms, dateadd

I created a query that must will get be controlled by a datetimepicker, what I am aiming to do is that I will get the next 7 days of the designated date set by the datetimepicker

I tried it in my query but it seems to have no difference at all or my query codes were just wrong

```
     select count(PatientID) as id, Patient.FirstName, Patient.LastName, 
      Patient.MiddleName, " +"Patient.Nickname, Patient.Age, 
       Patient.Birthday, Patient.Sex, Patient.Occupation, 
       Patient.CompleteAddress, Patient.MobilePhone, Patient.Phone, " +
       "Patient.PersonTCI, Patient.PContact, Patient.DateofC 

       from Patient 

        Where DATEADD ('d' , 7 , datetimepicker1 ) and Active = '1' " + "

        Group by Patient.FirstName, 
        Patient.LastName, Patient.MiddleName, 
        Patient.Nickname, Patient.Age, Patient.Birthday, Patient.Sex, 
        Patient.Occupation, Patient.CompleteAddress, " +
        "Patient.MobilePhone, Patient.Phone, Patient.PersonTCI, 
          Patient.PContact, Patient.DateofC"
```

Comment: What do you think or expect that `Where DATEADD ('d' , 7 , datetimepicker1 ) and Active = '1'` will do ?

Comment: Are you wanting to get the next 7 days after the selected date in the datetime picker, or the 7 days before? What date value are you comparing it against in your query? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    select count(PatientID) as id, Patient.FirstName, Patient.LastName, 
          Patient.MiddleName, " +"Patient.Nickname, Patient.Age, 
           Patient.Birthday, Patient.Sex, Patient.Occupation, 
           Patient.CompleteAddress, Patient.MobilePhone, Patient.Phone, " +
           "Patient.PersonTCI, Patient.PContact, Patient.DateofC 
       from Patient 

        Where Patient.DateofC>=Patient.DateofC and Patient.DateofC<= datetimepicker1.value.AddDay(7)     and Active = '1' " + "

        Group by Patient.FirstName, 
        Patient.LastName, Patient.MiddleName, 
        Patient.Nickname, Patient.Age, Patient.Birthday, Patient.Sex, 
        Patient.Occupation, Patient.CompleteAddress, " +
        "Patient.MobilePhone, Patient.Phone, Patient.PersonTCI, 
          Patient.PContact, Patient.DateofC"
```

Answer (score 0):

In where clause the condition for date comparison is missing. 
How about this.

```
var dateFrompicker = datetimepicker1.AddDay(7);
select count(PatientID) as id, Patient.FirstName, Patient.LastName, 
      Patient.MiddleName, " +"Patient.Nickname, Patient.Age, 
       Patient.Birthday, Patient.Sex, Patient.Occupation, 
       Patient.CompleteAddress, Patient.MobilePhone, Patient.Phone, " +
       "Patient.PersonTCI, Patient.PContact, Patient.DateofC 

       from Patient 

        Where dateFrompicker >  Patient.DateofC   and Active = '1' " + "

        Group by Patient.FirstName, 
        Patient.LastName, Patient.MiddleName, 
        Patient.Nickname, Patient.Age, Patient.Birthday, Patient.Sex, 
        Patient.Occupation, Patient.CompleteAddress, " +
        "Patient.MobilePhone, Patient.Phone, Patient.PersonTCI, 
          Patient.PContact, Patient.DateofC"
```